# tenants.php route file points to root directory

Tags: php, laravel-5.6

I'm experimenting with `hyn/laravel-tenancy` package. I am amazed how awesome it is, but I've run into issue.

`$this->get('login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');` causes error `Class Auth\LoginController does not exist`. Same with `Auth::routes()`.

But `$this->get('login', 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');` works fine.

How do I fix this to use it as a `web.php` routing file?

Comment: Why cannot you use the working example that you have provided?

Comment: Because it feels like anti-pattern workaround, rather than a solution. I can't use `Auth::routes()`. It goes against "don't repeat yourself" rule